# Wrong name in grub

Tags: grub2

This question is at least partly about linux mint but it also has Ubuntu in it so I decided to ask it here.  I recently update linux mint 16 to 17. I did this using apt instead of a fresh install. It finished and when I rebooted my computer the linux mint grub option disappeared. (My computer triple boots Ubuntu, Mint and windows 7) However there was a new option that simply said 'Ubuntu'. I chose that and it started loading Mint! Is there away to change the name back to Mint? (I already tried Grub customized and it listed it as linux mint not ubuntu so it didn't help)

Comment: How did you update it? Is Mint managing grub or Ubuntu?